# What should I install to my C and D drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, installation, performance, speed

I have two physical drives:

C Drive: HDD 266/372GB FREE
D Drive: HDD 328/542GB FREE

My OS is installed to the C drive.

Steam and Origin games are installed to my D drive, taking up around 210GB of space. Documents/Pictures/Downloads are also on my D drive.

I'm unsure which drive I should install programs to, e.g. Adobe, iTunes, Chrome, Skype, MS office, Steam and Origin Client. Currently, they're installed on my C drive.

Would it be better to install all programs to the D drive as well as games? Would there be a significant performance increase if I installed the programs to the D drive instead of the C drive?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. Unfortunately, your question is considered Off-Topic here on SuperUser, because there is no factual answer to give, only opinions. Please see the help center to learn what kind of questions are considered on-topic.

Comment: While your question is off-topic, I suggest not worrying about which drive your data is stored to, specifically due to the information you've provided in your question. Unless one drive is of a higher speed, or one is an SSD, it won't matter. Most people tend to dedicate a drive that meets their usage needs, so if you need ~500GB space for Steam and miscellaneous programs, use the larger one. If one is an SSD, use the SSD as your boot drive. That's based on what I've seen others do, but I don't see how it'd help in your situation if their only difference is disk size.

Comment: So installing the programs on the C or D drive won't significantly affect performance. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Speed may or may not be affected but one issue to consider is if anything happens to one of the drives. Assuming a program stores data on that same drive it is installed on, if that drive fails, that data will be gone. This is less of a consideration than it used to be since modern Windows programs often store data in AppData (which is on the C drive unless perhaps you take special care to change that) but some programs still store data on the install drive by default. This is a good reason to at least investigate where programs save data and possibly choose installation drives accordingly.